# SQL Join Through 3 Different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

Hey guys I have a SQL statement that i am really struggling on. Im basically trying to create a media player in vb.net and have a table structure set up as follows-

**SONGS_DB-**
*Song_ID, Song_Name*

**SONG_PLAYLIST**
*Song_playlist_id, Song_id, Playlist_ID*

**PLAYLIST**
*Playlist_ID, Playlist_Name*

The problem im facing is displaying all the songs in a certain playlist as it requires following a chain between 3 tables. I currently have a combo box set up displaying all the names of the playlists, when the selected index in my combo box is changed i want my datagridviewer to show all the song names that are within the selected playlists name.

This is essentially all the code i have as i dont even know where to start with this one-

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim con As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\coolj\OneDrive\Documents\Loop\Loop\Songs_SQL.mdf;Integrated Security=True"}
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT SONG_ID, SONG_NAME FROM SONGS_DB WHERE SONG_ID IN (SELECT SONG_ID FROM SONG_PLAYLIST WHERE PLAYLIST_ID IN (SELECT PLAYLIST_ID FROM Playlist WHERE PLAYLIST_NAME = (@NAME)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)

End Sub
```

All help appreciated x

Comment: Doesn't your combo box contain the `Playlist_ID` value? That would be better to search on than the name. But either way, your `Select` statement is missing 2 closing parenthesis. And try to incorporate table `JOIN` per the answer below from Arnaud.

Comment: Thanks didn't see that! Im now however getting this error- Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Party Hits                    ' to data type int.'

Comment: (Party Hits is one of the playlist names), Any ideas why this is occuring?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you can join table with clause `JOIN`. Here is what you need :

```
SELECT S.Song_Name, P.Playlist_Name
FROM SONGS_DB AS S
JOIN SONG_PLAYLIST AS SP
    ON S.Song_ID = SP.Song_ID
JOIN PLAYLIST AS P
    ON P.Playlist_ID = SP.Playlist_ID
```

Comment: The first Join should be `S.Song_ID = SP.Song_ID`

Comment: True, ty very much !